# Segmentation Fault Dynamically allocated array of structures

Tags: c

I want to parse a `.csv` file of the form: `grade(float), year(int), name(string), county(string), number(int)` and I don't see my mistake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 300

typedef struct{
    char *name, *county;
    float grade;
    unsigned long int year, number;
}info;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("lab3.txt", "r");
    if(!fin)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR OPENING THE FILE.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char buf[MAX];
    while(fgets(buf, MAX, fin))
    {
        buf[strcspn(buf,"\n")] = '\0'; // remove the trailing newline
        char *fields[6], *word = strtok(buf, ",");
        int i = 0;
        while(word)
        {
            info *array = (info *)malloc(sizeof(info));
            fields[i] = word;
            array->name = strdup(fields[2]);
            array->county = strdup(fields[3]);
            array->grade = atof(fields[0]);
            array->year = atoi(fields[1]);
            array->number = atoi(fields[4]);
            printf("Name : %s | County: %s | Year : %ld | Grade : %f | Number: %ld",array->name, array->county, array->year, array->grade, array->number);
            //printf("Word : %s\n", fields[i]);
            word = strtok(NULL,",");
            i++;
            free(array->county);
            free(array->name);
            free(array);

        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

There are exactly 5 fields on each line, so I wanted to break each line into words andI also used gdb to check what's wrong and the problem seems to be here `array->name = strdup(fields[2]);`. I've tried numerous things so far, I've allocated memory for the array and the name and county, I'm freeing the memory so, what's the mistake?

Comment: You need to call `strtok` 5 times - once for each field - before you can start copying the data to the struct.

Comment: Also, there's no need to call `malloc` and then `strdup`. You are only allocated room for one byte anyway - remove the `malloc` calls.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I can't believe I wasted hours on something so trivial. Thank you!

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I've edited but I also changed the second loop. Everything that I did on name, county, grade, year should be in the first loop so that the words are first copied into `fields`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

You don't really need [nor want] either `fields` or `word`. You can just use `realloc` to increase the size of the array and operate on the current pointer directly.

Doing `malloc(sizeof(char))`, as you have it, just leaks memory because of the `strdup` after it.

You do *not* want to do `free` at the bottom of the loop--it just kills what you did `strdup` for.

You are *not* expanding the size of `array` on each iteration [using `realloc`], so your array size stays at one. And, you blow away the previous value on each iteration, so, again, you're leaking memory.

Here's a refactored version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 300

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *county;
    float grade;
    unsigned long int year;
    unsigned long int number;
} info;

#define TOK \
    ({ \
        cp = strtok(bp,","); \
        bp = NULL; \
        cp; \
    })

#define SAVE_S(_sym) \
    arrcur->_sym = strdup(TOK)
#define SAVE_F(_sym) \
    arrcur->_sym = atof(TOK)
#define SAVE_I(_sym) \
    arrcur->_sym = atol(TOK)

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("lab3.txt", "r");

    if (!fin) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR OPENING THE FILE.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[MAX];
    info *arrbase = NULL;
    int arrcnt = 0;
    int arrmax = 0;
    char *bp;
    char *cp;

    while (fgets(buf, MAX, fin)) {
        // remove the trailing newline
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';

        // enlarge array -- use of arrmax limits number of realloc calls
        if (arrcnt >= arrmax) {
            arrmax += 100;
            arrbase = realloc(arrbase,sizeof(*arrbase) * arrmax);
        }

        // point to current array entry
        info *arrcur = &arrbase[arrcnt];

        bp = buf;

        SAVE_S(name);
        SAVE_S(county);
        SAVE_F(grade);
        SAVE_I(year);
        SAVE_I(number);

        printf("Name : %s | County: %s | Year : %ld | Grade : %f | Number: %ld",
            arrcur->name, arrcur->county, arrcur->year, arrcur->grade,
            arrcur->number);

        ++arrcnt;
    }

    fclose(fin);

    // trim to size used
    arrbase = realloc(arrbase,sizeof(*arrbase) * arrcnt);

    return 0;
}
```