# Array of Strings only storing the LAST item in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a program in which I read information in from a file, and sort it on different columns chosen by the user. I am not concerned about the sort at this moment, I just can't seem to properly store the data, and I am only getting the last set of items from the file when I try to read it into this array. The problem is that I need the pieces of information in a particular order, for sorting them later on. In my actual code I will be working with like 146 rows and 4 columns, and sorting on different columns.

**I can not use dynamic memory allocation for this project.**

**This is a simple example of what I'm trying to do but this is not my actual code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *array[2][3]; // Array to store the stuff, like a dataframe??
  int i;
  char name[10]; // Over-writable array to store name
  char age[3]; //Over-writable array to store age
  char occupation[12]; // Over writable for occupation



  for(i=0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    scanf("%s %s %s", name, age, occupation); // Get name, age, and occupation as input from file
    array[i][0] = name; // assign name to row position i, and column position 0
    array[i][1] = age; // assign age to row position i, and column position 1
    array[i][2] = occupation; // assign age to row position i, and column 2
    // i becomes one after this to move to row 1, column assignments
    // should stay the same
  }

  printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s\n", "Name", "Age", "Occupation"); //Print column headers

  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s\n", array[i][0], array[i][1], array[i][2]); //Print corresponding info
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So lets say I run this, and I manually type in:

```
Steve 50 Retired
Alex 23 Server
```

My output looks like this:

```
Name                 Age                  Occupation
Alex                 23                   Server
Alex                 23                   Server
```

The reason I need to store the info in a temporary array is because in some cases, I only need certain pieces of information, and can omit others. For example - I may need to produce a text file that is sorted by name, and includes Occupation, but does not include age, in which case I only need an array of names and ages.

No matter what I do I am only getting the last element of any given list of data. This could be an array that is 200 rows and 4 columns, and I would only get the very last entry from whatever file I'm reading from, and they would all print in the correct format using only the last piece of info given.

I may be going about this in entirely the wrong way too, if you have any ideas let me know.

My knowledge of arrays in C might be failing me, I am having a hard time grasping the pointers vs arrays thing, but I can't find a large scale 2D example that helps me through this.

Comment: Use strdup() when assigning strings

Comment: On each loop iteration, you're _reusing_ the same memory buffer area. Change (e.g.): `array[i][0] = name;` to `array[i][0] = strdup(name);`. Likewise for the other fields. For a slightly more advanced usage [using a `struct` vs a 2D array], see my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66464177/segmentation-fault-dynamically-allocated-array-of-structures/66464515#66464515

Comment: @tstanisl Dude, that was it! If you have any explanation to offer as to why it is this way, please let me know. It works perfectly now. Good lord it's been like 3 days looking for this answer.

Comment: What does your input look like, and what should the output look like? If you need to sort the data, it would probably be much easier if you can read all the data into memory, but that needs dynamic allocation. Though I suppose you could just `mmap()` the file to memory and in-place sort it. (Also, `strdup()` is also dynamic allocation.)

Comment: @bannedfromquestioning To understand what's going on, you should read about pointers and dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: The use of strdup() is not the answer: ' I can not use dynamic memory allocation for this project'.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I can see that now. Thank you all for clarifying on that one. Would've cost me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `strdup` is certainly an option, it uses dynamic memory allocation (don't forget to free it), which you say you can't use.

The suggestion here is to create your own type to store all the information you are gathering in an organized fashion, for that you can use a `struct`.

This makes the sorting process easier as you can then easily use [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) with a custom comparator function to sort your array in any way you need without much trouble.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[10];       
    char age[3];         
    char occupation[12]; 
}Info;

// comparator function example, sorts by alphabetical order of name
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    return strcmp(((Info*)a)->name, ((Info*)b)->name);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Info array[3];
    Info temp; // temporary variable you said you need

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // parse into temporary variable
        if(scanf("%9s %2s %11s", temp.name, temp.age, temp.occupation) == 3)
        {
            // if all goes well assign it to the data container
            array[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    qsort(array, 3, sizeof *array, compare); // sorting the array

    printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s\n", "Name", "Age", "Occupation"); //Print column headers

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%-20s %-20s %-20s\n", array[i].name, array[i].age, array[i].occupation); 
    }
}
```

Notice that I also added width limits to your `scanf` to avoid buffer overflows, I'm also checking its return value, these are things that should be done for a more robust code.

It seems to me that a better alternative would be to use `fgets` to read the inputs/file and `sscanf` to parse the values.

The code above will produce, for an input:

```
richard 23 engineer
albert 45 driver
charles 24 lawyer
```

The output:

```
Name                 Age                  Occupation
albert               45                   driver
charles              24                   lawyer
richard              23                   engineer
```

Sorting the array alphabetically, by name.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't allocate any memory for these char* that you get from scanf,
you can directly use mmalloc , and strcpy, or alternatively you could use strdup to do both at once.

since you're basically copying the pointers from name/age/occupation each single time, you end up with the same values since they contains the last scanf call result.

simple case or what you're doing:

```
char* strarray[2];
char* str ="hello";
strarray[0]=str;  
strarray[1]=str;
```

both arrays elements contains the SAME pointer
so now if i change str :

```
str ="Not Hello";
```

both array element will still point to the same pointer, hence will contains the same string "Not Hello".

Comment: What you're saying is not wrong, but you should probably elaborate more and think about how you format the answer.